# Deal with Array of Hashes or single Hash ( from an API Response)

Tags: ruby, api

I have an API that is responding with either:

1. An Array of Hashes

   ```
   results = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a:2, b:3}]
   ```
2. A single hash, if only one result

   ```
   results = {a:1, b:2}
   ```
3. Or `nil`

I'm trying to work out an elegant way to deal with the situation so I can add an extra parameter where it's present.

e.g. 
Situation 1:

```
results.map!{|h| h.update(c:3) }
```

Situation 2:

```
results[:c] = 3
```

Situation 3:

```
(Don't do anything)
```

I've tried

```
if results.is_a?(Array)
  results.map!{|h| h.update(c:3) }
elsif results.is_a?(Hash)
  results.update(c:3)
end
```

But it looks ugly, messes up the code around it (and I've got a bug that I can't pin down)...

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: That's a terrible api. They probably didn't care about the users.

Comment: I would say it is an API design failure. The second case should be `[{a:1, b:2}]`, and the third case `[]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my api...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this should work for you.

```
 # API Simulator
 def call_api
    # Lets return randomly - one of the three results
    [ [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a:2, b:3}], {a: 1, b:2}, nil ].sample
 end

 5.times do 
    r = []
    r << call_api
    p r.flatten.compact.map { |h| h.update(c:3) }
 end
```

Above code can also be written like below:

```
5.times do
  p  [call_api].flatten.compact.map { |h| h.update(c:3)}
end
```

The output will be array always, it may be empty or if it contains hashes, it will have `{ :c => 3 }` in each of the hashes.  One of the sample run produces below output:

```
[]
[{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}]
[]
[{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}, {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>3}]
[{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}]
```

Comment: Now replace `([] << call_api)` with `[call_api]` and it will even look pretty.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you can use `case` to test types.

```
def type? item    
    case result
       when Array
           "array"
       when Hash
           "hash"
       else
           "couldn't figure it out"
    end
end
```

That would clean up your code and not make it a bunch of nested ifs.

Answer (score 0):

You want to

> "add an extra parameter where it's present."

So, when we will successfully add an extra parameter, it will not be single any more so as the documentation says:

> A single hash, if only one result
>
> results = {a:1, b:2}

Without much thinking we can do that when result is not `nil`:

```
array.new(results).flatten.append(c:3)
```

So one possible solution could be:

```
newhash={c:3}
if result.nil? ? array.new(results).flatten.append(c:3) else newhash end
```

But I have a feeling that this is not the best solution :P

Answer (score 0):

Normalizing the API response to array (even it has 0 or 1 hash) will help you:

```
results = [results].flatten.compact
```